# sort() produces different results in Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: r, windows, ubuntu

I have a vector that is being sorted differently when I run the code on my Windows vs. Ubuntu remote server.

Windows:

```
> u <- getNodes(network)
> head(u)
[1] "-1336623650" "-1749477680" "539"         "-1036241023" "6135"              "-44987577"  
> uid <- sort(u)
> head(uid)
[1] "-1000019199" "-1000022360" "-1000039153" "-1000044219" "-1000069199" "-1000099640"
```

Ubuntu:

```
> u <- getNodes(network)
> head(u)
[1] "-1336623650" "-1749477680" "539"         "-1036241023" "6135"
[6] "-44987577"
> uid <- sort(u)
> head(uid)
[1] "10"          "100"         "1000"        "10000"       "-1000019199"
[6] "-1000022360"
```

Both implementations of R have the same packages loaded and are the same R version (3.3.1). Ubuntu is 13.10 and Windows is Windows 7.

Comment: It looks like the Ubuntu version is sorting on the absolute value or ignoring the - sign.  Is there anything less negative than "-1000019199" in your vector?

Comment: Your vector appears to be a character string.  If you convert to numeric the sort behavior should be consistent between operating systems.

Comment: The `sessionInfo()` from both machines may be revealing. Collation of characters will depend on the locale in use.

Comment: If you matched your charset encodings between windows and Ubuntu you would also get consistent, though still numerically incorrect results.  Neither sort algorithm is sorting on "ascii" order, which is not what we as programmers typically expect.  Single Byte Character Set sort is dead, I guess.

Comment: And z <- c("-1","1", "20", "21", "200"); sort(z) will of course not be correct numeric order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String sorting (which is what you are doing) in R is based on the "locale" which is different for Windows and Linux systems.  But, do be careful.  No locale will sort these strings in correct numerical order, you would have to sort a vector of numbers if you wanted numerical order.

Grab the value of Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE") from each system and compare them. For my package, I do the below at the entry point, and report it in packageStartupMessage.

```
collateOrigValue<-Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE",collateOrigValue), add=TRUE)
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE","C")
```

See also https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html

Answer (score 6):

Use `stringi::stri_sort` or `stringr::str_sort` for consistent sting sorting across operating systems.